# Function call when on change is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have 2 dropdown boxes. one dropdown box sets another dropdown box. The second dropdown box's value is used to populate a Date. For whatever reason the value that is used to set the date is always the previous value in the 2nd drop down box. I want to get the latest value not the earlier value.

Note this is razor and they are partial classes.

I've tried using a .when done (commented out below).
I even tried calling the SetCurrentQualDate inside the load

It always gets the preious value and nothing seems to work

```
    $("#requalifty-wps-dd").change(function () {


        $("#requalify-process-dd").load('@Url.Action("GetProcessName_Requalify", "Home")'+ "?selectedWPSID=" + $("#requalifty-wps-dd").val());//,SetCurrentQualDate());
        $('#requalify-process-dd').prop('disabled', false);

        //$.when(loading != null).done(SetCurrentQualDate());
        //$.when(loading).done(SetCurrentQualDate());
        //SetCurrentQualDate().after(callBack($("#requalifty-wps-dd").val()));


    });
        //.done(SetCurrentQualDate());


    $("#requalify-process-dd :selected").change(function () {
        SetCurrentQualDate();
    });
```

I want to get the latest value from the load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking on something that is async, using get instead of load should do the trick:

```
 $("#requalifty-wps-dd").change(function () {

     $.get('@Url.Action("GetProcessName_Requalify", "Home")' + "?selectedWPSID=" + $("#requalifty-wps-dd").val(), function(data) {

         $('#requalify-process-dd').html(data).prop('disabled', false);
         SetCurrentQualDate()
     });
     $('#requalify-process-dd').prop('disabled', false);
 });
```

Comment: I'm getting an SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags

Comment: Also get seems to return all the values